# fill report from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, datatable, report

i need to ask you because i've searched everywhere and can't understand the logic so please be patient
i try to create a report viewer in c# form and want to fill this report by data from datatable that already been filled from query

```
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("query_string", Welcome.con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.TableName = "DataTable1";
    da.Fill(dt);
```

till here i filled the datatable and no problem
but when i try to use this code which i found everybody use it gives me "namespace could not be found":

```
    ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("DataTable1", dt);
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
    reportViewer1.DataBind();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

i don't know if i have to include library or something?? and i wonder if this code is enough to fill the report with the query result?? so please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a `using` block to the top of your .cs source file:

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms
```

The `ReportDataSource` is defined in the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` assembly, so you might have to manually add a reference to it to the project too.

Comment: it works thank you but still give me error for 
reportviewer1.databind(); for databind it tells no defintion